# Evento que identifica disparo de outro evento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um evento jQuery que vem de um framework, e preciso disparar um evento especifico no fim do disparo desse evento que não está previsto.

Seria algo como isso:

Evento do framework

```
var evento = function() {
    $(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
       //Faz algo
       return response;
    })
}
```

Evento que indentifica o disparo anterior, o disparo é hipotético, mas o que ele vai fazer é só isso mesmo:

```
$(document).on('eventoFoiDisparado','evento',function(){
    $('.fiscal-target-close').trigger('click');
})
```

Sei que posso usar o `eventListener`, mas nunca precisei antes, e não estou conseguindo aplicar porque o evento do framework em questão, é um evento universal, ou seja, vai disparar em muitos locais diferentes, e eu preciso em uma situação especifica.

OBS: Esse evento do framework está dentro de uma `function` iniciada com `.init`.

OBS2: O Evento que eu quero disparar ao disparar o outro evento é avulso a qualquer outra função, é apenas pra corrigir um problema de exibição de resposta.

Comment: Sua pergunta ao meu ver não está muito clara, não consegui entender exatamente o que você deseja. Você disse que o evento não está previsto no framework, mas colocou um trecho de código do evento do framework. Em seguida exemplificou o que deseja fazer, capturando o evento disparado. Qual sua dificuldade então?

Comment: To com dificuldade em entender como identificar o disparo de um evento com outro evento, ou como usar o eventListener pra identificar isso. PS: o framework é próprio, se não for muito viável fazer isso, também quero saber pra modificar o framework.

Comment: De forma simplória: Ao clicar em um botão, e terminar o que o evento do click fez (isso é feito pelo framework),  fazer outra coisa que não estava no evento original (seria o evento avulso que eu preciso).

Comment: Se você tiver como modificar o framework e ao final do evento em questão, emitir um novo evento indicando que terminou aquela execução, seria a melhor forma. Só assim pra garantir que há uma sequência na execução. Outras formas poderiam não serem executadas na ordem que você quer.

Comment: @PedroSouza pensei nisso também, é que isso realmente só vai ser disparado uma vez em um lugar que raramente é usado, mas acho que fica mais bonito não fazer gambiarra mesmo kk